# searching for a novel with a sideplot of mad scientist sociologists attempting to institute a theocracy via mechanical monsters

Tags: story-identification

A novel written in english, in which one of the sideplots was a group of mad scientist sociologists who'd concluded that theocracy would the best political system, if its tendency of inevitably being taken over by power-hungry corruption instead of true believers could be avoided and this could be accomplished by making actual consequences for lack of faith. Specifically, by building self-replicating mechanical monsters which were programmed so that they could be warded off by specific ritualized rules and prayer necessitating the existence of a priestly caste in society to perform said rituals and prayer and on a randomized period measured in centuries, the rules of said rituals and prayers would randomly change to shake things up for the priestly caste.

Comment: "Gather, Darkness!" by Leiber?

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez My memory of "Gather, Darkness!" is that the theocracy was thoroughly corrupt, and that any monsters were illusions created by the resistance movement.

Comment: @user888379 Yes, I had my doubts about how well the answer fitted, which is why I put it in a comment rather than an answer. It's also not really a "sideplot" - it's pretty much the whole plot!

Comment: Hmm.  Scott Spencer's "Last Night at the Brain Thieves' Ball" had a crowd of mad scientists including sociologists, with a variety of strange ideas for manipulating  people and society.